# How to run simple command on startup on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, startup

I need to run a command at startup on my machine using FreeBSD:

```
cd /home/portal
mv portal.sqlite corrupt_portal.sqlite
```

This is clearly not a daemon or a service, just a one time command at every boot.

I tried to put a .sh file inside /usr/local/etc/rc.d/ with `#!/bin/bash` and it doesn't do anything, I also tried to simply write `touch testfile`
If I run both versions manually they work with no problem.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I'm not sure you're missing anything, https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/articles/linux-users/startup.html - You can see the order using rcorder: https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/etc-rc-d-versus-usr-local-etc-rc-d.6532/ .

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52036993/4694621

Answer (score 5):

The [rc(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rc&apropos=0&sektion=8&manpath=FreeBSD+11.2-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html) script is responsible for running the automatic boot process, and the example section of the manual gives a simple template for the `/etc/rc.d/` directory. Read the [rc.subr(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=rc.subr&apropos=0&sektion=8&manpath=FreeBSD+11.2-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html) manual page for further guidance on writing startup scripts.

However, one of the final stages of the automatic boot process is to read a script file called `/etc/rc.local` (if it exists). This file requires no special formatting or keywords, or the execute bit set.

From the `rc(8)` manual page:

> Typically, the /usr/local/etc/rc.d/ mechanism is used instead of rc.local these days but if you want to use rc.local, it is still supported.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to put that command to the `crontab`.
Instead of first five fields usually filled by asterisks you can place the special token `@reboot`

```
@reboot root:wheel /path/to/the/command [args ...]
```

This command will be launched each time the system been rebooted.