# How to restart Anydesk every time I restart the PC using FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, remote, remote-desktop, anydesk

Actually I'm using Anydesk on freebsd 13R to allows access to some coworkers. I have two problems to fix with FreeBSD and Anydesk :

1. Anydesk server closes when the remote user closes the client
2. Anydesk does not restart when the PC is rebooted. Maybe is needed a script to put in the right location on FreeBSD.

Someone can help me to understand how to fix these problems ?

Comment: 1 sounds weird - I've used AnyDesk for a few years now across OS:s (not BSD tho'), never had the server close when I close client session. Are you sure the user's actually closing the client? 2. Does [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/468196/how-to-run-simple-command-on-startup-on-freebsd) help you get it started at boot time?

Comment: actually I have placed the anydesk executable inside the kde autostart tools and it seems that everytime that kde starts anydesk is ran. Anyway,when I close the anydesk window instead of minimize it,it is not reachable anymore. can u install freebsd in virtualbox to repeat the behavior.

Comment: LOL I actually installed FreeBSD a few days ago, but haven't even gotten a window manager running yet... :-D So can't help you there, unfortunately. I just did a quick test with a Win VM tho. I actually can kill the remote server, on the server itself; not by shutting down my client locally. And the local client still shows the server online. I can also close my local client's connection on the remote end, via my client. So... are you sure the users are actually disconnecting by closing their local client, not on the remote end?

Comment: when the client tries to connect to the server,on the screen of the server I see a window that tells that someone wants to connect. If I close that window,instead of minimize it,the server daemon closes. maybe the behavior of the windows version is different.

Comment: So it's working as designed. While AD works with client/server model, it doesn't run as a daemon. It actually has only has one executable - that's both the client _and_ the server. You can minimize the window, but if you close it you shut down the server. It works this way on Windows, Linux, MacOS and iOS - personal experience, both directions - so I'd expect it to work exactly the same way on BSD.

Comment: I really don't like that it doesn't run as a daemon.

Comment: Yeah, I can understand that. I've not found a way to run it as such, but then again I've not been trying very hard either. I think AD:s primarily intended as a remote support tool than a permanent solution, seeing that even on Windows it doesn't install by default.